# Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::$_data has no effect

Tags: cart, enterprise-1.13

We just started on a new project and this error has come up from time to time. Restarting Apache seems to correct the issue, but I would like to find the root of the error

EE 1.13.0.2

Full error

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::$_data has no effect  in /html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 270

#0 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(270): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Indirect modifi...', '/var/www/foodse...', 270, Array)
#1 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(677): Varien_Object->setData('_has_data_chang...', true)
#2 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(265): Varien_Object->__set('_hasDataChanges', true)
#3 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(677): Varien_Object->setData('_data', Array)
#4 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(109): Varien_Object->__set('_data', Array)
#5 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Varien_Object->__construct(Array)
#6 /html/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('checkout/cart', Array)
#7 /html/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::getModel('checkout/cart', Array)
#8 /html/app/code/community/Webshopapps/Wsafreightcommon/Model/Observer.php(250): Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
#9 /html/app/code/community/Webshopapps/Wsafreightcommon/Model/Observer.php(245): Webshopapps_Wsafreightcommon_Model_Observer->_getCart()
#10 /html/app/code/community/Webshopapps/Wsafreightcommon/Model/Observer.php(141): Webshopapps_Wsafreightcommon_Model_Observer->_getQuote()
#11 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Webshopapps_Wsafreightcommon_Model_Observer->hookToControllerActionPostDispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Webshopapps_Wsafreightcommon_Model_Observer), 'hookToControlle...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(551): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(75): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->postDispatch()
#16 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(422): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->postDispatch()
#17 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#18 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /html/index.php(87): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#22 {main}
```

I got this error today - it doesn't include WSA

```
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::$_data has no effect  in /html/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 270

#0 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(270): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Indirect modifi...', '/var/www/foodse...', 270, Array)
#1 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(677): Varien_Object->setData('_has_data_chang...', true)
#2 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(265): Varien_Object->__set('_hasDataChanges', true)
#3 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(677): Varien_Object->setData('_data', Array)
#4 /html/lib/Varien/Object.php(109): Varien_Object->__set('_data', Array)
#5 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Varien_Object->__construct(Array)
#6 /html/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('checkout/cart', Array)
#7 /html/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::getModel('checkout/cart', Array)
#8 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php(166): Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
#9 /html/app/design/frontend/enterprise/hock/template/checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml(35): Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar->getSummaryCount()
#10 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/foodse...')
#11 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#12 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(605): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(549): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topCart', true)
#16 /html/app/design/frontend/enterprise/hock/template/page/html/header.phtml(38): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topCart')
#17 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/foodse...')
#18 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#19 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(605): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(549): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#23 /html/app/design/frontend/enterprise/hock/template/page/1column.phtml(45): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#24 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/foodse...')
#25 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#26 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#32 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#33 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#34 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#35 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /html/index.php(87): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#39 {main}
```

Comment: I just noticed all the WebShopApps items in there... sorry I will take a look at those lines now.

Comment: Also, restarting the Web Server clears the issue

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14323/

Comment: I saw those posts, but they were from 2008 so I was a little reluctant to look into it there. I will take a closer look

Comment: I am actually more interested in finding out why it works fine once I restart Apache

Comment: Here is what seams strange to me. Why is there a call to `Varien_Object->__set('_data', Array)`? It's like the `_data` member var does not exist and when calling `$this->_data = '..'` it calls the magic `__set` method. I don't think the problem is Magento itself. I think it's your server configuration. APC or something like that?

Comment: so, if you disable APC do you get the same result?

Comment: We have not received any errors.... yet!!